# SpringBoot migration, failing to configure DataSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, migration

I am trying to migrate a SpringBoot app from version 2.1.5.RELEASE to 2.7.7. The project uses Maven and Java 8.

After changes in pom.xml the app won't start:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Here is the old pom.xml that is working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
      <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <demo.profiles.active>local</demo.profiles.active>
      <demo.build.skip.frontend>true</demo.build.skip.frontend>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
      <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z</maven.build.timestamp.format>
      <commons-lang3.version>3.3.2</commons-lang3.version>
      <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.7.201606060606</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
      <aws-java-sdk.version>1.12.60</aws-java-sdk.version>
      <spring-integration-aws.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-integration-aws.version>
      <jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
      <geda.core.version>3.1.2</geda.core.version>
      <springfox-swagger2.version>2.7.0</springfox-swagger2.version>
      <frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>v6.9.4</frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>
      <caffeine.version>2.8.1</caffeine.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>    
       <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
       <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
       <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.42.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-aws</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-integration-aws.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.inspire-software.lib.dto.geda</groupId>
        <artifactId>geda.core</artifactId>
        <version>${geda.core.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.statemaczze</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-statemaczze-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>    
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>         
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/conf</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/${demo.profiles.active}/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources2</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/conf/${demo.profiles.include1}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/${demo.profiles.include1}/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources3</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/conf/${demo.profiles.include2}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/${demo.profiles.include2}/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>static/**</include>
                    <include>db/**</include>
                    <include>testdata/**</include>
                    <include>bitsensor.properties</include>
                    <include>templates/**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>conf/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <demo.profiles.active>local</demo.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>conf/local/*</include>
                            <include>logback-spring.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm run ng -- build --progress=false</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run prod</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion}</nodeVersion>
                            <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Here are only the changes I did in pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
...
```

Added

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Changed flyway dependency because we are using Mysql 5.6

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Replaced Swagger with SpringDoc

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

From db.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/prod?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
```

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=local
spring.config.location=conf/local
```

From the MainClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAuthorizedFeignClients
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/application.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/poller.properties"})
@EncryptablePropertySource("classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/db.properties")
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/s3.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/mail.properties"})
@EncryptablePropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/security.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/afm.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/pdf.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/authy.properties"})
@PropertySource({"classpath:${spring.config.location:conf/local}/sqs.properties"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

The app builds without errors and in the target folder the correct properties files are included with the correct data in both: target/conf/ and target/classes/conf/local/.
However, when starting the app, I see that neither **local** is set as active profile and from the error I see that neither db url is picked from the property file.

Here is the output when starting app

```
2023-01-10 14:14:18 [main] INFO  {com.demo.Application.logStarting:55} - Starting Application using Java 1.8.0_275 on MacBook-Pro.local with PID 44230 
2023-01-10 14:14:18 [main] INFO  {com.demo.Application.logStartupProfileInfo:631} - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"  
2023-01-10 14:14:22 [main] INFO  {o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn:132} - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.  
2023-01-10 14:14:23 [main] INFO  {o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn:201} - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1171 ms. Found 290 JPA repository interfaces.  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {o.s.i.c.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.info:292} - No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {o.s.i.c.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.info:292} - No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.setSerializationId:283} - BeanFactory id=f01228a5-0c91-3af5-87a8-5de938b7d5f3  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.c.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory:50} - Post-processing PropertySource instances  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource configurationProperties [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource] to AOP Proxy  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource cachedrandom [org.springframework.cloud.util.random.CachedRandomPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource springCloudClientHostInfo [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/sqs.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/authy.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/pdf.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/afm.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/mail.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/s3.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/poller.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter.makeEncryptable:39} - Converting PropertySource class path resource [conf/local/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper  
2023-01-10 14:14:24 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.f.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter.lambda$null$2:31} - Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver.lambda$null$2:31} - Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector.lambda$null$2:30} - Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize:108} - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {o.a.catalina.core.StandardService.log:173} - Starting service [Tomcat]  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine.log:173} - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].log:173} - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext  
2023-01-10 14:14:25 [main] INFO  {o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.prepareWebApplicationContext:292} - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7169 ms  
2023-01-10 14:14:26 [main] ERROR {o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup:61} - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePoolMetadataMeterBinder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/jdbc/DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration$DataSourcePoolMetadataMetricsConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourcePoolMetadataMeterBinder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class  
2023-01-10 14:14:26 [main] INFO  {o.a.catalina.core.StandardService.log:173} - Stopping service [Tomcat]  
2023-01-10 14:14:26 [main] WARN  {o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh:591} - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat  
2023-01-10 14:14:26 [main] INFO  {o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logMessage:136} - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.  
2023-01-10 14:14:26 [main] ERROR {o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.report:40} - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
  
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63663', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If active profiles and connection parameters are provided from the command line (-Dspring.profiles.active=local ...) the app creates a DataSource and "local" is set as active profile.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the jasypt-spring-boot-starter 2.1.1 dependency is not compatible with SpringBoot 2.7.7. So the solution was to to update the dependency to 3.0.5

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
   <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```